# Make check box items indent like an unorderded list inside a list?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make check box items indented like Unordered list items inside a ordered list?

[Here is the mock-up](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B2FGtcAkvLlbH--oMqh6OScf2K_TYXHEpleCUU99BBQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The major issue I faced so far that is multi-line text will not indent. and I don't want make a table just for that layout.

The requirement is IE8 (I know, I know, but it is for banks).

**New Update:**
I end up using something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ms3fX/1/), it works well with IE8 and reasonable well in Firefox 22:

```
<div>My list starts here.</div>
<ol>
    <li>First item
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" /><span class="CheckBoxSpan"></span>
        <label>Checkbox item one, it also need be indent probaly like an list item, what happens if it has more than one line, it need be indentes, not wrap</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" /><span class="CheckBoxSpan"></span>
        <label>Another checkbox item one, again it also need be indent probaly like an list item, what happens if it has more than one line, it need be indentes, not wrap</label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And CSS

```css
.CheckBoxSpan 
{
 position: relative;
    left: 4em;   
}
li label 
{
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:80%;
    vertical-align:top
}
li input 
{
    width: 1.4em;
    margin-left: -1.9em;
}
```

Comment: You'll get a fair better response from the people on here if you're able to share code so that we can see where you're up to, and demonstrate specific points that you might be struggling with.  In theory this could be very easily achieved using inheritance and margins/positioning in the CSS, but it's all dependent on what your markup looks like and what you've already achieved.

Comment: better if w/ fiddle too! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more info it's difficult to figure out what you want, but I think this may come very close. Just give the labels for the checkboxes display:block. And some cosmetics to make it look right.

```
li label {display:inline-block; max-width:80%; vertical-align:top}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6VyL6/1

If that's not what you're after, you may have to show some code of your own.

Comment: Thanks for that, the indent for input checkbox works well, I think that solved my main issue, I may need reduce the margin/padding of the checkbox block to make the boxes vertical align with numbers, then the label need space between them and boxes.

Comment: If you really want the textboxes to appear in the same place as the list numbers, I'm not sure that can be done in a way that works across browsers. Sure you can slap `display:relative` on the checkboxes and the labels, but you won't always know where the browsers draw those numbers. It may look right on one but terrible on another.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about the way I am doing now is not guarantee to working in different browsers; in fact I would be surprised if it works well across browsers. I probably will let client know that it can be done as exactly requirement layout, but it wouldn't be a good solution as it will be broken in different browsers. I would rather keep it simple than broken.

Comment: Normally it is better to put checkboxes and its labels inside a list or just leave it as you did?